# Windows 7 Icons, Buttons, and Tabs corrupted...Professional 32-bit

Tags: windows-7, display, 32-bit

The other day, about two or three ago, I was simply typing in a Microsoft Word document when my screen froze.   After a few moments, it went black...I thought it was my vid hardware (dual nVidia 9800 GTs).

Anyway, I did a hard reboot, and chose to Start Normally.  The system blue screened telling me there was a failure in the Memory Manager.  So then I thought maybe a RAM failure or vid memory failure.

I attempted reboot again, this time I got presented with the option to repair windows...so I went with that.   The repair app finished and did an auto reboot.  This time I got all the way back to my desktop where in a matter of a about 30 seconds, the system blue screened again and pointed to the Memory Manager as the area of cause.

Again I rebooted, the repair thingy came up again and I allowed it to do its thing.  Deciding if the same failure occured I'd begin pulling hardware to see at what point I may have found the possibly defective party.

However, this time it rebooted, I got back to desktop and no crash.  All looked well, untill I looked at the baloon messages when hovering over the System Bar icons.  Also when I opened any of my browsers, the tabs had no text, and any window that pops up that has regular buttons (OK, Cancel, etc., etc.) looks weird.  The buttons are really really long and have no text.

So it seems like the system is once again running smoothly, however something has gotten corrupted.. something relating to drawing basic windows user interface objects.

Help...all ideas are respected and appreciated.  Have a great day everyone!

Comment: Can we get a screenshot?

Comment: I would try to boot from e.g. an Ubuntu CD and run memtest86. This will idenify problems with your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you question something weird happened..

1. Check your Hardware (Usually:PowerAdaptor,RAM Memory)
2. Run a check Disk (If not possible do it from Command Prompt in Windows Recovery CD or a Repair Live CD)
3. If all above are Ok, Boot from the Windows Recovery CD then choose Repair Windows)
   Restore your system to an earlier Restore Point.
4. If it´s simply the icons but I doubt you may have to Rebuild the Icon Cache in Windows 7

[Windows 7 - Icon Cache - Rebuild](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html) from the SevenForum tutorials